# How to prevent Beamer from loading amssymb and amsfonts?

Tags: beamer, mathdesign, amssymb

I would like to use the `mathdesign` package and the `charter` font in my `beamer` presentation. But when using

```
\usepackage[charter,cal=cmcal]{mathdesign}
```

I get the following warnings (sic!):

```
Package 'amssymb' shouldn't be used in conjonction with package mdbch
Package 'amsfonts' shouldn't be used in conjonction with package mdbch
```

I already found out that the `beamer` package is responsible for this since it loads `amssymb` and `amsfonts`. But does it really need them? What is the correct way to handle this or should I just ignore the warnings?

Comment: without specific experience, i'd guess that it's not a good idea to ignore these particular warnings.  i suggest getting in touch with the author of `beamer` and request an option to omit loading these files.  actually, it's only necessary to omit loading `amssymb`, since that's what loads `amsfonts`.

Comment: A year on, would you say you can safely ignore the warnings, or is it really necessary to use the hack below?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simple hack is as follows

```
\RequirePackage{scrlfile}
\makeatletter
\AfterPackage{beamerbasemodes}{\beamer@amssymbfalse}
\makeatother
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\usepackage[charter,cal=cmcal]{mathdesign}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{\rmdefault}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
What will the font be? $\twoheadrightarrow$

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Explanation: `beamerbasemodes` sets the conditional to true and afterwards `beamerbasefonts` is loaded, which checks whether the conditional is true and, if so, it loads `amssymb`.

However there *should* be a `noamssymb` option also for `beamer` as there is for the `beamerarticle` package. Not providing it is an error, in my opinion. The existence of the conditional is meant for using it, but `beamer` doesn't and simply sets it to true.

Answer (score 9):

I know, it is just a hack, but you could try

```
\expandafter\gdef\csname ver@amssymb.sty\endcsname{9999/12/31}
\expandafter\gdef\csname ver@amsfonts.sty\endcsname{9999/12/31}

\documentclass{beamer}

\global\expandafter\let\csname ver@amssymb.sty\endcsname\relax
\global\expandafter\let\csname ver@amsfonts.sty\endcsname\relax

\usepackage[charter,cal=cmcal]{mathdesign}
```

The first two lines make latex believe in having loaded the packages already.
The next two lines just prevent `mathdesign` from assuming that the packages have been loaded.